# Making @Fetch work with interfaces

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have created a data-access layer containing Spring Data Neo4j classes **which are accessed behind interfaces**.

For example, I have a Car interface and a CarNode class that uses SDN annotations like `@RelatedTo` :

```java
@RelatedTo(elementClass = CarNode.class, type = "drives", direction = OUTGOING)
private Set<Driver> drivers;
```

If you look closely, you'll see that the @RelatedTo refers to the `CarNode` class and the `drivers` is defined as `Set<Driver>` (and not `Set<DriverNode>`).

This works fine.

Now I would like to use `@Fetch` to enable eager-loading.

If I simply do :

```java
@RelatedTo(elementClass = CarNode.class, type = "drives", direction = OUTGOING)
@Fetch
private Set<Driver> drivers;
```

I get the following error :

```
Type interface org.my.project.Driver is neither a @NodeEntity nor a @RelationshipEntity
```

Is this possible to tell `@Fetch` that it should expect `DriverNode`, just like it is possible with `@RelatedTo` when we use `elementClass` attribute?

I would like to avoid breaking my current architecture. Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been more than a year since I posted this question. Reading it again, the problem is obvious to me now : *I was **completely** misunderstanding and misusing the `elementClass` attribute*. When I wrote:

```
@RelatedTo(elementClass = CarNode.class, type = "drives", direction = OUTGOING)
private Set<Driver> drivers;
```

this is **wrong**, **wrong**, **wrong**.

The solution to my original question is to use the interface inside the field declaration (`private Set<Driver> drivers;`), and the concrete implementation of the interface in the "elementClass" attribute of `@RelatedTo`.

This is how it works now in my project:

```
@RelatedTo(elementClass = DriverNode.class, type = "drives", direction = OUTGOING)
private Set<Driver> drivers = new HashSet<Driver>(0);
```

So, the only place where you have to use the `DriverNode` concrete class is inside `elementClass` attribute. You don't need to use generics at all.

**Foot-note** : I don't use `@Fetch` anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I've faced a similar issue and I solved it using the implementation class in the `Set` field, i.e.

```
@RelatedTo(type = "drives", direction = OUTGOING)
@Fetch private Set<DriverNode> drivers;
```

After all the `drivers` collection is private, hence it's an implementation detail.
To enforce access by interface you can declare get/set methods which return/take as parameter instances of the interface type:

```
public Set<? extends Driver> get Drivers() {
    return drivers;
}

public void setDrivers(Set<? extends Driver> drivers) {
    this.drivers = (Set<DriverNode>) drivers;
}
```

In the `set` method you have to cast the `Set<Driver>` collection to `Set<DriverNode>`, but this doesn't break the interface rule, since it's again an implementation detail hidden by the public interface.

Comment: Hi Remigio. I tried your idea, and I get `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Set<DriverNode> to Set<Driver>`. It doesn't seem possible to cast a Collection. Are you sure this is what you used?

Comment: My fault, I've edited my answer with the correct code.

Comment: Thanks, this works. The only drawback is that my interfaces now show `Set<? extends SomeInterface>` which doesn't seem as simple as `Set<SomeInterface>`.

Comment: This was a concern of mine too, anyway it's a price one can pay to get a better abstraction.